# ValueError: expected sequence of length 19 at dim 1 (got 5) when using Hugging Face

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I'm using HuggingFace to create a fine-tuned GPTNEO model.

Here is my code

```
import datasets
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPTNeoForCausalLM
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments
import pickle
dataset = load_dataset('text',data_files={'train':['youtube_3/script.txt','youtube_3/endgame.txt','youtube_3/infinitywar.txt']})
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('EleutherAI/gpt-neo-1.3B')
model = GPTNeoForCausalLM.from_pretrained('EleutherAI/gpt-neo-1.3B')

print(dataset)
pickle.dump(dataset,open('youtube_3/avengers.pickle','wb'))
def tokenize(bruh):
    return tokenizer(bruh['text'])
tk_dataset = dataset.map(tokenize)
ttk_dataset = tk_dataset['train']
training_args = TrainingArguments('test_trainer')
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model, args=training_args, train_dataset=ttk_dataset
)
trainer.train()
model.save_pretrained('youtube_3/avengers')
```

But whenever I do this I get this error

```
ValueError: expected sequence of length 19 at dim 1 (got 5)
```

Since all the pytorch is handled in HuggingFace itself I don't know what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

FULL TRACEBACK

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*************/Documents/vsc/youtube_3/sadge_ai.py", line 20, in <module>
    trainer.train()
  File "/Users/*************/miniforge3/envs/python386/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1258, in train
    for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator):
  File "/Users/*************/miniforge3/envs/python386/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 521, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/Users/*************/miniforge3/envs/python386/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 561, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/Users/*************/miniforge3/envs/python386/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 47, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "/Users/*************/miniforge3/envs/python386/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py", line 66, in default_data_collator
    return torch_default_data_collator(features)
  File "/Users/*************/miniforge3/envs/python386/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py", line 107, in torch_default_data_collator
    batch[k] = torch.tensor([f[k] for f in features])
ValueError: expected sequence of length 19 at dim 1 (got 5)
  0%|
```

I believe this has to do with my training data but I'm not sure.

Comment: Post the full traceback

Comment: Try: ```tokenizer(bruh['text'], return_tensors="pt").input_ids```

Comment: @Ulto Did you solve this problem?